# What is the right way to parse a CSV, making asynchronous http requests, once all the requests return, to then use the aggregated data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, asynchronous

Here is what I'm working with:

```
  readableStream.pipe(csv.parse({
    auto_parse: true,
  }))
  .on('data', function(row) {
     parseRow(row)
     parseRowSomeMore(row)
     useRowInfoInAsyncHTTPRequest(row)
     useRowInfoINAsyncHTTPRequestAgain(row)
  });
  readableStream.on('end', function() {
    doSomethingWithParsedRowsAndReturnedAsyncRequestData();
  });
```

Hopefully what this example code examples is that I'm reading the CSV file, and on every chunk of data (which is row information), I want to parse this row somehow, and also make an asynchronous HTTP call using the row information. Finally, after reading the data, I want to use the aggregated data once all the asynchronous requests and row parsing has been complete. However, what I'm encountering is that after node reads the last chunk of data, it automatically triggers the 'end' emitter, but the last asynchronous requests may not have been processed yet, and therefore the information in the 'end' emitter does not reflect all the information I want.

1. Is this the structure/process I want for reading a CSV using node?
2. If this is the structure/process, how do I ensure that I receive all the required asynchronous information before the 'end' emitter triggers?

Comment: Your question title makes it pretty clear that this question is too broad. Perhaps you could split it into multiple questions and ask them separately? Or maybe you could just reword it so it's asking 1 concise thing

Answer (score 0):

You can store a count of how many `data` events have been received, how many have been resolved, and a boolean for whether the stream is ended. Each time an async http request completes, you increment `resolved`, and `if ended && resolved === received`, then you `doSomethingWithParsedRowsEtcEtc()`.